# How to convert a string to a hashed value and revert it back?

Tags: java, hash, md5

I need 2 methods: One to convert my string value to a hashed value, using md5 would be nice, and the other to revert the hashed string to its original one. Is this possible?

Comment: hashing is like a meat grinder. Cow goes in, hamburger comes out. You cannot feed hamburger into the same grinder and expect to get a cow out. You want encryption, not hashing.

Comment: If you want to check the validity of the original hash, just re-hash the user input and compare it with the original hash. Otherwise, the whole purpose of the hash ("impossible" to get the original input value back) is completely pointless.

Comment: @MarcB *"Cow goes in, hamburger comes out."* Plus or minus a few steps. I like to use the hash brown analogy, ie: you can't turn hash browns back into a potato.

Comment: @NullUserException: depends on who the butcher is. I'm sure some of the bigger food conglomerates won't bother with niceties such as butchering or deboning.

Answer (score 4):

It's *impossible* to turn a hash back to the original input string, by the very definition of hashing functions, they can't be inverted. And besides, there's potentially an infinite number of inputs which hash to the same value, although in practice they're very, very hard to find (they're called "collisions").

Regarding the other part of the question, it's simple to calculate a hash using standard libraries. For example:

```
byte[] bytesOfMessage = yourString.getBytes("UTF-8"); // pass the right encoding
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");  // specify the algorithm
byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);         // here's the hash
```

Comment: Easy with the emphasis, we have rainbow tables and other stuff.

Comment: @MightyPork A rainbow table won't allow you to retrieve the original value with 100% certainty, only one possible input.